# Kernel Modules. How can I modify printk severity based on a passed parameter?

Tags: linux

I have a kernel module that's working just fine. I'm able to pass parameters during the insmod stage, but I'd like to create a parameter "verbose". When set to true, my printks move from KERN_INFO to KERN_ERR severity.

I'd rather not double the number printk lines with an "if(verbose)" above each one. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, the usual way is to stick the priority level in front of the format string and let the preprocessor concatenate the strings

```
printk(KERN_INFO "blah\n");  // turns into 
printk("\001" "6" "blah\n"); // turns into
printk("\0016blah\n");
```

But that's not mandatory, there are some drivers that output the priority level from a `%s` format specifier, so you could just do:

```
printk("%smessage\n", (serious ? KERN_ERR : KERN_INFO));
```

(reading the code, that seems to be [explicitly supported](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/kernel/printk/printk.c?id=refs/tags/v4.7.4#n1681).)

---

Though, verbosity usually refers to printing out more information, which might be useful too. To do that, you'd need to create a wrapper for `printk` that checks the verbosity level first. (Or actually, you need  `vprintk` to pass in a `va_list`):

```
__printf(2, 3) int myprintk(int onlywhenverbose, const char *fmt, ...) 
{
    if (onlywhenverbose && !verbose) 
        return 0;

    va_list args;
    int r;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    r = vprintk(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    return r;
}
```

And then use with `myprintk(1, KERN_INFO "message only shown when verbose\n")`. The `__printf(a, b)` is defined in [`include/linux/compiler-gcc.h`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h?id=refs/tags/v4.7.4#n119) and expands to `__attribute__((format(printf, a, b)))` which tells gcc to [check the function arguments](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) like it does for `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not include the printk() statements without any #ifdefs.  If you need them all you have to do is change the setting of the loggers to collect this information.  This is basically done by a lot of programs...I.E. incorporating debug information but using logging parameters to get the information out.

Comment: I don't want to flood the kernel dmesg buffer if I don't need to.